# Sens de « à nous faire souffrir nous-mêmes » (La Peste, Camus)

Tags: sens, prépositions, verbes, littérature

> Pour parler enfin plus expressément des amants, qui sont les plus
> intéressants et dont le narrateur est peut-être mieux placé pour parler, ils se trouvaient tourmentés encore par d'autres angoisses au nombre desquelles il faut signaler le remords. Cette situation,  en effet, leur permettait de considérer leur sentiment avec une sorte de
> fiévreuse objectivité. Et il était rare que, dans ces occasions, leurs propres défaillances ne leur apparussent pas clairement. Ils en trouvaient la première occasion dans la difficulté qu'ils avaient à imaginer précisément les faits et gestes de l'absent. Ils déploraient alors l'ignorance où ils étaient de son emploi du temps ; ils s'accusaient de la
> légèreté avec laquelle ils avaient négligé de s'en informer et feint de croire que, pour un être qui aime, l'emploi du temps de l'aimé n'est pas la source de toutes les joies. Il leur était facile, à partir de ce moment, de remonter dans leur amour et d'en examiner les imperfections. En temps ordinaire, nous savions tous, consciemment ou non, qu'il n'est pas d'amour qui ne puisse se surpasser, et nous acceptions pourtant, avec plus ou moins de tranquillité, que le nôtre demeurât médiocre. Mais le souvenir est plus exigeant. Et, de façon très conséquente, ce malheur qui nous venait de l'extérieur et qui frappait toute une ville, ne nous apportait pas seulement une souffrance injuste dont nous aurions pu nous indigner. Il nous provoquait aussi **à nous faire souffrir nous-mêmes** et nous faisait ainsi consentir à la douleur. C'était là une
> des façons qu'avait la maladie de détourner l'attention et de brouiller les cartes.

Comment doit-on comprendre la partie en caractères gras et pourquoi ?

- 1/ « à tel point qu'il nous faisait souffrir aussi » ?
- 2/ « dans le but de nous forcer à nous infliger nous-même de la souffrance »
- 3/ « à prendre une attitude par laquelle nous acceptions l'image qu'on s'était faite de nous même » ?

Au « 2/ » et au « 3/ », le phrasé peut être modifié si on pense ainsi améliorer l'interprétation.

Comment: Le contexte global de l’œuvre me pousse à comprendre comme ta suggestion 2/.

Comment: Ce qui semble être aussi ce qu'a compris le traducteur du roman en anglais (Penguin edition, traduction de Stuart Gilbert, 1948). [p. 63](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.527316/page/63/mode/2up).

Comment: @None Les commentaires ne doivent pas être utilisés pour les réponses.

Comment: Franchement dire que je comprends comme toi n'a rien d'une réponse. Une réponse nécessiterait de justifier en recherchant dans l’œuvre les éléments justificatifs, bref, faire une explication de texte et je n'en ai pas envie ! Trop fastidieux et chronophage. Même si j'apprécie beaucoup Camus par ailleurs.

Comment: @none Je ne sais pas, « 3 » ne me semble pas une mauvaise idée non plus.

Answer (score 1):

"Provoquer à" doit être compris dans le sens de "amener à", "forcer à".

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/provoquer

> B.− Qqn/qqc. provoque qqn à (vieilli).Inciter, pousser quelqu'un à.

Comment: Oui, c'est évident pour moi. Et c'est aussi ce qu'a compris le traducteur du roman en anglais.

Comment: Oui, ça ne correspond par contre pas tout à fait à la suggestion 2/ de la Q. Ce n'est pas provoquer au sens d'une provocation.
(Par ailleurs dans le cas présent, j'ai un avis divergent sur Camus dont j'avais oublié combien il pouvait être froid et ampoulé. Son style n'aide pas vraiment à la compréhension ici...)

Answer (score 0):

Aucune de ces trois possibilités, ou pas tout à fait. 1 implique une "limite". 2 implique un "but". 3 implique une "image". Mais le malheur provoque simplement les amants à se faire souffrir eux-même parce qu'ils sont séparés et que cette séparation les pousse, par le souvenir, à réexaminer leur amour et ses imperfections. 3 serait le plus proche, si "l'image" était celle de leur relation avant la peste. Mais il n'y a pas forcément d'acceptation non plus, juste une souffrance accrue.